# Download interrupted: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to download SDK 7, I receive the peer not authenticated error. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change proxy edit your gradle.properties

HTTPS:

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

HTTP:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
```

Or

Change repositories in the build.gradle

```
repositories {
    maven  {
        url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try check this:

```
Force https://... sources to be fetched using http://...
```